# Accessing Pycharms virtual environment with terminal

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv, pythonpath

I am trying to work with pycharm's virtual environment and want to be able to access it in the terminal.

My question is this:
When i add a path to the project interpreter

settings -> Project Interpreter -> the small wheel -> show all -> tree symbol on bottom right -> add my project path here

i can import my projects as modules. when I do sys.path they also show up in the python console. But when I activate my venv in bash and look at the syspath

python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"

The modules dont show and I cannot import them by accessing python through activated venv. Why that? how do I run a PyCharm venv from the terminal (inside or outside of pycharm?)

I already tried to activate the virtual env in terminal using

source ./activate

and launched python from there. I cannot import my modules from here. I dont want to launch pycharm from here. Im working on Ubuntu16.04 with python 3.7.

Comment: What operating system is this on?

Comment: Its on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: What directory do you run `source ./activate` in? What is the output when you print `sys.path`? Please show an example where you attempt to import modules. Be sure to include the output as well.

Comment: I did source ./activate in bin folder of my virtual environment. The sys.path shows correctly all my expected folders when i run it in python console but not in terminal. in terminal it shows only path to my anaconda3/lib/python.